# CSRFGuard loading javascript inject in script tag

Tags: jakarta-ee, csrf, owasp

I am trying to work with CSRFGuard API to fix CSRF Vulnerability in my application.
For that purpose I am using Javascript injection to do so.

I am doing so by including the following line in my jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascriptservlet"></script>
```

When I run it with localhost, it gets loaded in browser perfectly.
But when I host my application on a server, it doesnot get loaded. I looked in the response headers and it says

```
The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists
```

I tried to change the script tag like :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://<servername>:<port>/appcontext/javascriptservlet"></script>
```

but I get same result in response headers and the response from "javascriptservlet" doesnot loaded in browser which is a JavaScript.

Also when I hit the url in the browser's address bar, I get the response with the Javascript successfully but it is failing to load the Javascript when referred from  tag

I am really stuck with this thing . Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: PErhaps there is any CSP header blocking this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. It was a minor tweek. Just corrected the referer-pattern in web.xml where JavaScript servlet configuration is defined.